# returning fuzzy match percentage in solr query result

Tags: lucene, solr, fuzzy

I've implemented solr/lucene fuzzy match for my system and its working perfectly.

I have requirement to display percentage fuzzy match after query sends response back.
As an example if my index data is "rushikupadhyay" and if my query is "rushikupadhya"~0.8, I should get exact percentage as part of response like 0.85 or 85%.

I want to use percentage result as part of application and perform additional steps based on return value, like if percentage match is 70-80% do X, 80-90% do Y, and > 90% do Z.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

**Please Note:** The guidance found in this post on the [Lucene Wiki - ScoresAsPercentages](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages) that you may want to review before deciding to go with a purely percentage based logic.

However, if you do decide to go with a percentage value, you can get this value by also including the score field in the query response. See the Solr Admin page (Full Interface link) will direct you to /admin/form.jsp In the **Fields to Return** option it shows, `*,score` This will return the match score for each document in the result set. However, please note that this is the raw score of the document match and is relative to the `maxScore` value that is part of the `<result>` element. So in order to get the true percentage based score for each document, you will need to normalize each documents score against the maxScore by using logic such as `(score/maxScore * 100)` to get the correct percentage value to display.

Comment: That recommendation (in the link) does not apply in this specific case. Yes, the natural score of a match is tied to the whole body of documents in the index, but fuzzy queries are based on the Levenshtein distance, which does have a value in [0,1] independently of the other documents. I think that's what the OP wanted to display in the results